# SIM card adapter for A/B/N/AC card slot

Tags: laptop, networking, network-adapter

So, I want to have my laptop (HP Pavillion model 15-bc401la) take a SIM card, for that purpose I want to swap out its wifi card (Realtek RTL8822BE) for an adapter:
[image]
Unfortunately I haven't had luck finding one online that matches the pinout and measurements... since my knowledge on network cards is essentially nil, I would like to know how to find such an adapter, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Stack Exchange Hardware Rec!

That is a NGFF (M.2) Key A/E which is weird for laptop WLAN cards they are usually Mini PCI-E, anyways [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C998WDLX) is probably something you're looking for. They are a few different variants, you might have to buy another WLAN card as well so it doesn't lose the ability for WiFi.

They actually make usb SIM card dongles that you can buy, some are cheap and some are expensive, I personally never have used one but have seen them so I can't say how reliable they are, but it is a possible option.